# ÃŸ Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_header

Tags: php, wordpress

Code Wizards,

I currently have a website that uses `wordpress`, and recently had some malware problems. I deleted some files without thinking what they did. While trying to restore the site after getting internal sever errors, I soon started to get errors similar to the one below. However I'am stuck on this one, on what it means/wants me to do.

> ÃŸ Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_header() (previously declared in /hermes/bosnaweb10a/b2702/ipg.cjhgraphicdesigncom/wp/wp-includes/general-template.php:21) in /hermes/bosnaweb10a/b2702/ipg.cjhgraphicdesigncom/wp/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 43

I would really appreciate any knowledge on this, my php skills are not the best.
Thank you!

Comment: Show us the full script of `link-template.php` and `general-template.php`! The error means that you try to define the function `get_header()` twice

Comment: Best bet in your situation (malware problems) might be to back-up the database & wp-content files and start with a fresh install of WP.

Comment: @Rizier123 those are WP core files, which can be huge and shouldn't have gotten messed with anyways. That's why I think a fresh start would do some good here.

Comment: @mopo922 I'm not the WP expert, but if these are core files then i would start fresh too :D It's like your php installation is damaged

Comment: Yes for some reason lost a lot of core files. I have been using github to copy and paste files like "link-template.php & class-wp-theme.php"; core files. What do you mean by a fresh start/install, where can I get that?

Comment: I got the download stupid question see if this works

Comment: fresh install of core files plugin and i got dashboard and hmpg but the subpages get an "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."